# Why is the special characters hidden in HTML, but shown with the title attribute? And what can I do about it?

Tags: html, special-characters, title

Given this script:

http://jsfiddle.net/wnhL6co6/

```
<div title="Standard Jet DBµnb`">Standard Jet DBµnb`</div>
```

You can see that the text contains special characters. When rendering the HTML, they are escaped. However when doing mouse over to show the title, the special characters are displayed.

[image]

Two questions:

1. Why the inconsistency?
2. Is there a way to make them show the same value for to user?

Comment: Seems to depend on your browser/OS/font. Mac Safari shows the mouse-over text fine, too.

Comment: You mean Safari on MacOS, the special characters are not rendered either in the title?